# Exception with SimpleMembership and ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, membership

I create new ASP.NET MVC4 project with account controller uses forms authentification.
Then I run project and register new user for creating database file.
Then I create some tables in new mdf database file and I use ADO.NET Entity Data Model for this new tables instead of membership's tables.
After creating model.edmx there are two connection strings in web.config file.

```
    name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.LAModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.LAModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.LAModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LAWebProject-db.mdf;initial catalog=aspnet-LAWebProject-db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"


    name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-LAWebProject-db;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LAWebProject-db.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

The project debugs few times then crashed with following exception:
    Can not connect to the database server SQL Server.
Please help me to resolve it...

Comment: When you say "the project debugs a few times" do you mean that you are able to successfully access the database? If so, then there's nothing wrong with your code, your SQL 2012 LocalDB is stopping for some reason.

Comment: Yes, i debuged project 5 minutes ago successfully, but now i heve the same exception, and i didn't change anything in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing that `"\"` from your connection strings:

```
|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LAWebProject-db.mdf;
```

becomes

```
|DataDirectory|aspnet-LAWebProject-db.mdf;
```

If it doesn't work, check that the db file `aspnet-LAWebProject-db.mdf` exists in the `App_Data` folder.

Make sure your LocalDb instance is running too:

[LocalDB: Where is My Database?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx)

Comment: Did you check the the db file exists in the correct folder? Is your LocalDb up? Can you connect to it using Server Explorer within Visual Studio?

Comment: And i have DefaultConnection in Data Connections.

Comment: Yes, i see only one connection in Data Connections. I can create new tables and i have other 5 tables for membership (UserProfile, webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles, webpages_UsersInRoles

Comment: Can you add in your question a screenshot of the error message?